# Um passaro a voar em direção a norte = passaro voando em direção a norte?

Tags: gramática, verbos

Me topei com uma frase parecida à do título. É gramatica desconhecida por mim.

Tenho duas questões principais:

1. Posso usar "a -inserte verbo" e "gerundio do verbo" de forma intecambiável?
2. Quais são as regras gramaticais do uso "A -inserte verbo-" como na oração do título?

Comment: Uma pergunta com uma resposta tão simples...sem seguimento. Credo.

Answer (score 2):

Em Portugal, a estrutura: estar + gerundio é geralmente exprimida por:

estar a verbo no infinitivo.

**Um passaro está voando** [etc.] = Brazil

**Um passaro está a voar** [etc.]. = Portugal.

Esse uso é a maior diferença que se ouve no dia a dia entre as duas variedades de português.

Além disso, em títulos, se faz abstração do verbo estar.